# LiveStreaming Media Player Error (1, -2147483648)

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Android media player unable to play the livestream

```
url = rtsp://v3.cache8.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQmXovF6e-Rf-BMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
```

But plays the http url= http://www.pocketjourney.com/downloads/pj/video/famous.3gp

This is the error log

```
03-07 12:16:32.702: E/MediaPlayer(869): error (1, -2147483648)
```

Comment: Want to play Video in YouTube Player??

Comment: duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765605/online-video-not-playing

Comment: So for that you have to use YouTube API and simple pass video id.

Comment: are you streaming in device or in emulator ?

Comment: @kedarnath in emulator

Comment: @user2988855 Run it in real device rather than in emulator.

Comment: Emulator may not support it. Its not your code's fault. Just test it on any real device. You should get proper output.

Comment: i am checking on device also but it not works used device is xolo q800

Answer (score 0):

This error in general means: `Media Type not supported`

I had a similar issue (for AudioStreams) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15225076/android-aac-radio-streaming-doesnt-work-with-mediaplayer-android-4-2-2-sho)

Don`t trust emulator. It could be, that you are redirected to another link, depending on your device.

Comment: i am checking on device also but it not works used device is xolo q800